# Parsing with fscanf() ignoring spaces or missing values?

Tags: c++, xml

I'm trying to scan a text file with XML, the XML has a number of items with this structure:

```
<enemy>
  <type> 0 </type>
  <x> 273 </x>
  <y> 275 </y>
  <event> </event>
</enemy>
```

The problem is that the xml may have spaces between tags or inside them. I created a loop and I'm trying to do a single scan in each iteration to get int type, x, y and event into a variable each. However I don't know how to ignore whitespaces nor how to handle missing values since some tags may or may not have a value (like event).

How can I scan this "enemy" regadless of spacing and missing values?

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one - you **do not** parse XML using `fscanf()`. Use a real XML parser otherwise you will end up with a very complicated code that will not work 80% of the time either returning wrong data or crashing.

XML format (despite seeming simplicity) is complicated even in most innocuous cases and existing XML parsers are there for a reason. See [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) or a lot of others.

Still, if you are hell-bent on parsing XML yourself, the right way to do it is to first tokenize the input and then ensure that your token sequences result in correct forms. That's way more complicated than using simple `fscanf()`.

Comment: thanks, no I don't care about parsing it myself, I'll check what libraries are available.